# WxPython using Listbox and other UserInput with a Button

Tags: python, listbox, wxpython, web-crawler

I am trying to create a web crawler based on specific user input. For example, the User Input I am trying to receive is from a ListBox and a text field. Once I have that information, I would like the user to click a button to start the search with the information collected.

This is where I have been getting problems. The EVT function doesn't recognize the listbox since its been linked to the Button evt. Is there a way to solve the problem? Can EVT information be shared with other EVTs?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import wx  # for gui


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Title', size=(300,200))
        tournLevel = ['$10,000', '$15,000', '$20,000', '$50,000','$75,000','$100,000']
        levelBox = wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (40, 50), (90, 90), tournLevel)
        levelBox.SetSelection(1)  # default selection
        checkButton = wx.Button(panel, label= "Check Now", pos = (150, 50), size = (90, 40))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, checkButton)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        currLevel = event.GetSelection()
        print(currLevel) # to test if GetSelection is working


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I would be very happy if I could just get the button to recognize the ListBox results. 
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just grab it from the listbox, you don't need it from the event.  See below:

```
import wx  # for gui


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Title', size=(300,200))
        tournLevel = ['$10,000', '$15,000', '$20,000', '$50,000','$75,000','$100,000']
        self.levelBox = wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (40, 50), (90, 90), tournLevel)
        self.levelBox.SetSelection(1)  # default selection
        self.checkButton = wx.Button(panel, label= "Check Now", pos = (150, 50), size = (90, 40))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.checkButton)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        currLevel = self.levelBox.GetSelection()
        print(currLevel) # to test if GetSelection is working


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

More specifically, if you store levelBox as self.levelBox, it will be accessible inside the OnClick method as a MyFrame attribute.  You can then use the [GetSelection](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ListBox.html#ListBox.GetSelection) method for this object (*not* the event), which will get the current selection.

Comment: **NOTE** I just edited the code you posted, but it does _not_ run in its current state.   You are referencing a panel that is not defined -- if you change all references to `panel` with `self`, it should work.

Comment: I always recommend using a panel for the widget's parents. That makes the look and feel correct and adds the correct tabbing behavior. You won't get that if you make the frame the parent.

Comment: Totally agree, @MikeDriscoll.  That switch was the quickest fix to get his example working.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `levelBox` into a property of the class by turning it into `self.levelBox` and accessing it that way as @brettb mentioned. However you can get a bit sneakier and do it using a lambda for your callback to pass the Listbox widget to the event handler:

```
import wx  # for gui


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Title', size=(300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        tournLevel = ['$10,000', '$15,000', '$20,000', '$50,000','$75,000','$100,000']
        levelBox = wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (40, 50), (90, 90), tournLevel)
        levelBox.SetSelection(1)  # default selection
        checkButton = wx.Button(panel, label= "Check Now", pos = (150, 50), size = (90, 40))
        evt = lambda caller, widget=levelBox: self.OnClick(caller, widget)
        checkButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, evt)

    def OnClick(self, event, widget):
        currLevel = widget.GetSelection()
        print(currLevel) # to test if GetSelection is working
        print widget.GetString(currLevel)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Also note that you didn't have `panel` defined, so your original code doesn't work. See the following for more information:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks